# Can SimpleMembership be used with Google API v3, OAuth2 authentication?

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, simplemembership

For Google API v3, is it possible to use SimpleMembership instead of [Google Api Dotnet Client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/)?

This is for subsequent usage against their services like calendar and drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, the SimpleMembershipProvider for Google is an OpenID provider, not an OAuth2 provider.